# How do I save images directly into a MySQL database as a BLOB using django? These images are uploaded dynamically through the django admin panel?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, blob

What i want is that when i upload an image from the django admin panel, the image should be saved as a blob in MySQL database and not save the URL as django does when we use the imageField model.
What is happening:
upload image through admin panel -> url stored in database, image in folder -> image fetched via url in template
What I want:
upload image through admin panel -> convert image to blob -> store blob in database -> image fetched directly from database

Comment: Look at [`BinaryField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield). But this is generally **bad** design. It is best not to store files in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Create TextField in Model encode the file to base64 & Store in it.

```
import base64

from django.db import models

class Blob(models.Model):

    file = models.TextField(
            db_column='data',
            blank=True)

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.file = base64.encodestring(data)

    def get_data(self):
        return base64.decodestring(self.file)

    data = property(get_data, set_data)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer @pranav. But when the image file is a text field, how will I upload my image from the backend? I want a way where I upload the image as a .png/.jpeg and it dynamically gets converted to a BLOB and gets saved in the database.